# Javascript Scope - retrieve value from callback object and send as form

Tags: javascript, cakephp, callback, scope

My experience with javascript and with callback functions is limited, and I have a problem with them. I want to use a third party API to obtain some information, and than pass that on to my CakePHP controller so it can store the data into a db table.

Here is my function:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function()
    {
        var address = document.getElementById('target');

        geocoder.geocode(
            {'address': address.value},
            function(results, status)
            {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
              address.value = results[0].formatted_address;
              alert("Inside " + address.value);
            }
            else
            {
              alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });

        alert("Outside " + address.value);
     };
}
```

I have built in two alerts to get a grip of what's going on. The "outside" alert comes up first, showing the address as the user wrote it; after that the "inside" alert shows the address that I am after, but unfortunately, by the time the data gets to my controller, it's gone.

So... how would I go about fixing this? Address already is an object, and I read suggestions about just doing everything from inside your callback, but I don't see how I could do that in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Just do it server side. You're loading a new page anyway, so doing it client side won't save you a page load.

Comment: The third party API (google) has a per client limit of 2500, so I would rather make the request on the client side ;)

Comment: 2500 requests/day that would be, so it's more a matter of principle than of necessity - but it should be possible somehow

Comment: you can never get anything from callbacks, only do things.

Comment: Can I force the code to send the form from within the callback?

Comment: Please do not answer questions by editing them - add an answer (if one doesn't already exist) and accept it.